# How to add ucwords and strtolower to this form

Tags: javascript

I want "s.value" to be turned all to lowercase and then ucwords to it but I don't know how to do it since it's inside a form.

Basically I want to do something like this: ucwords(strtolower(   s.value here    ));

This is the form:

```
   <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/?s=" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s2').value.length > 5) window.location = action + '<php echo $city; ?>++++' + s.value; return false;" >
```

Thanks

Comment: Do it all in JavaScript, not PHP. PHP is server-side.

Comment: Phpjs.org provides JavaScript equivalents of PHP functions. Ucwords can be found at http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords:569

Comment: Can you be a little clearer, you clearly have demonstrated that you know how to embed php inside the form element and that you know the right syntax for using ucwords combined with strtolower. So what exactly are you asking? It looks to me like you are trying to use PHP to format a JS variable which is not possible if the `s.value` is created/obtained after the php has ran. If that is the case you will need a JS solution. But I am not sure if this is the case. Like I said, you need to be more clear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ucwords (str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

function strtolower (str) {
    return (str+'').toLowerCase();
}

</script>

<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/?s="  onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s2').value.length > 5) window.location = action + '<?php echo $city; ?>++++' + ucwords(strtolower(s.value)); return false;" >
```

The javascript functions are from [PHP.JS](http://phpjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I only needed the last part though

Answer (score 3):

Javascript String have two functions: toLowerCase() and toUpperCase, you can use them with

```
function toInitCap(input)
{
 input = input || "";
 return input.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1,str.length).toLowerCase(); 
}

toInitCap(s.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may, like me, want something that does this on one line, I used:

```
"your strING".toLowerCase().replace(/(?:(^.{1})|\ [a-z]{1})/g, function(a){return a.toUpperCase();})
```

returns `Your String`

Comment: Not as short as I'd like, admittedly.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ <?php echo ucwords(strtolower($s_value)); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do:

```
$out = ucwords(strtolower($_GET['s.value']));
```

If s.value is the input name you want to pass

Comment: I thought periods were converted to underscores for form field names in PHP?

Comment: They might be, I have never used a period in a form name, but he said that he wanted "s.value". You might be right on that one

Comment: There will be no `s.value` when the server side is processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it while they are editing the text within the text box then I'm not sure what you would do but if you want to make it lowercase then uppercase AFTER they submit the form then its simple.

ucwords(strtolower($_GET['formid']))

Answer (score 0):

**str.length => input.length**

```
function toInitCap(input)
{
 input = input || "";
 return input.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1,input.length).toLowerCase(); 
}

toInitCap(s.value)
```